# Issue iterating in while loop for multiple rows data from sql data using shell script Shell Programming and Scripting

Tags: sql, shell, unix, while-loop, cut

I am trying to retrieve data from a table in a bash variable(output) and looping through it to send the automatic mails .I am using the below script --

---

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(sqlplus -S UN/PW <<EOF
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
select h.run_seq_id || '^',
        h.email_id || '^',  
       h.EMAIL_SUBJECT || '^',
       h.target_system_business_owner || '^',
    ('abc') || '^' to_list, 
    ('xyz') || '^' cc_list
    -- b_row.html_body
from email_header h
where 1=1 
--and h.email_id = b_row.email_id    
--and h.email_id in (2501,2502)
order by h.run_seq_id, h.email_id;
exit;
EOF
)
echo "$output"
    while IFS= read -r line
    do  
        run_seq_id=$(echo $output | cut -d '^' -f 1) 
        echo 'col1:' $run_seq_id
        
        email_id=$(echo $output | cut -d '^' -f 2) 
        echo 'col2:' $email_id
        email_subject=$(echo $output | cut -d '^' -f 3) 
        echo 'col3:' $email_subject
        target_system_business_owner=$(echo $output | cut -d '^' -f 4)
        echo 'col4:' $target_system_business_owner
        to_list=$(echo $output | cut -d '^' -f 5) 
        echo 'col5:' $to_list
        cc_list=$(echo $output | cut -d '^' -f 6)
        echo 'col6:' $cc_list
done<<<$output
```

---

The data is not looping over all the rows instead it is reading the 1st row again and again . echo statements have the same data again and again i.e. it is reading the 1st row again and again and not looping through all the data .Could anyone please help me to get through this issue .I have omitted the sendemail statement from the script for now .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to preserve the line separation, we have to quote:

```
done <<<"$output"
```

(You would have seen the difference if you also wrote `echo $output`.)

Comment: but when i use "" quotes every row comes in the new line .Its not able to read through the data .It is just reading 1st row and then again 1st row and so on according to the iterarion it has.

Comment: What you describe is not reproducible; you'd have to execute the script with `bash -x` (or put `set -x` in) and show the output.

Comment: Hi ,can anyone answer my query .As i am stuck in this .Loop is not working